# How to show About dialog?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I see this video from flutter team https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFCSODyFxbE&t=0s
and when trying to add aboutdialog . error showing in under name . is anyone try this widget?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Call this method to view the dialog.

```
void _showDialog() {
  showAboutDialog(
    context: context,
    applicationName: 'Flutter',
    applicationIcon: FlutterLogo(),
    applicationVersion: '1.0.0',
    children: [
      Text('This is an About Dialog in Flutter'),
    ]
  );
}
```